# XeTeX & Overprinting

Tags: xetex, pdf, printing

My printing house asked me to set black overprint feature on for my book which includes a lot of background images. I have no idea what is overprinting and after spending a long time of googling I found this [page](http://indesignsecrets.com/set-a-swatch-to-overprint.php) explains what is overprinting and how to tun it on in Adobe InDesign. Then I found this command in ConTeXt

```
\setupcolors[rgb=no,cmyk=yes,spot=yes,state=start,overprint=yes]
```

I don't find the equivalent in Latex. However, I found [overprint package](http://tex.aanhet.net/overprint/) but it doesn't work with XeTeX. Here is an example of what my book look like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}
%\usepackage[a5paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 total={148mm,210mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 bindingoffset=0mm,
 driver=xetex
 }

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pages=some,angle=0,opacity=1]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1]{arabic}
\parindent 0pt
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\chapterfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Tarablus}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\BgThispage
\backgroundsetup{ contents={\includegraphics[width=0.09\paperwidth,height=0.09\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{7}}, position=current page.center}

\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{flushright}
 \Large{أهدي هذا الكتاب إلى أفضل أصدقائي ورفيقة دربي زوجتي}
\end{flushright}



\end{document}
```

The result when I use Overprint Preview in Acrobat Prof looks like this:

[image: the output preview in Acrobat Prof]

I am looking for help in this issue.

Comment: The most expedient thing I've found to do is to just post-process the .pdf and turn over-printing on for text (one can use PitStop scripts to delimit it to only particular sizes and colours). Really though, the printer should be doing this for you --- it's a standard part of pre-press work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Zdenek Wagner](http://www.ctan.org/author/wagner) to help me in this issue. The answer is [zwpagelayout](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zwpagelayout) package. The background image should be in CMYK, otherwise overprint will not work. Here is his example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}
%\usepackage[a5paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
 %\usepackage{geometry}
 %\geometry{
 %a5paper,
 %total={148mm,210mm},
 %left=20mm,
 %right=20mm,
 %top=20mm,
 %bottom=20mm,
 %bindingoffset=0mm,
 %driver=xetex
 %}

\usepackage[a5,margins=20mm,footskip=20pt,overprint,cropmarks,color]{zwpagelayout}
% Notes
% Overprint requires cropmarks, this is a limitation of xdvipdfmx (not needed for other
% drivers
% footskip is the place reserved for pagination, without it the crop marks will be wrong

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{xcolor} % zwpagelayout does not work with xcolor
%\usepackage[pages=some,angle=0,opacity=1]{background} % loads tikz and tikz loads xcolor
%\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % this loads xcolor
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1]{arabic}
\parindent 0pt
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
%\newfontfamily\chapterfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Tarablus}

\begin{document}
\SetOverprint % set the overprint for the whole document
\color{cmykblack} % be sure that black is defined in CMYK, not in grayscale

\thispagestyle{plain}
%\BgThispage
%\backgroundsetup{
%contents={\includegraphics[width=0.09\paperwidth,height=0.09\paperheight,keepaspectratio]
%{
%7}}, position=current page.center}
% Be sure thet the background image is in CMYK, otherwise overprint will not work

% Background made in a different way
\vbox to 0mm{\centerline{\includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth]{8.pdf}}\vss}

% Note: rgb179.tif was converted to  cmyk179.tif using lcms
% and then to cmyk179.pdf
% The exact commands are
% tifficc -n -i AdobeRGB1998.icc -o eucmyk50.icm rgb179.tif cmyk179.tif
% tiff2ps -e cmyk179.tif | epstopdf --filter --outfile=cmyk179.pdf
% The ICC profiles are distributed with various products

\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{flushright}
 \Large{أهدي هذا الكتاب إلى أفضل أصدقائي ورفيقة دربي زوجتي}
\end{flushright}



\end{document}
```

However, there is a limitation in zwpagelayout. It does not support xcolor package right now which mean I can not use background package.